# How fast is css calc?

Tags: html, css, css-calc

Say I have a block taking up whole space and inside it a fixed width block centered like that:

```
<div>
  <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto">...</div>
<div>
```

If I was to minimize nesting of elements on my page, would following solution be slower?

```
<div style="padding: 0 calc((100% - 800px)/2)">
  ...
<div>
```

I tried to make benchmark, but I never did it so I probably messed it up somewhere:
http://jsperf.com/css3-calc-test/14

It shows that calc version is ever so slighly faster.

Comment: Yes it would be slower. Just avoid css calc where ever you can. You also could run a benchmark to see the truth;)

Comment: @bub - so I've made the benchmark here: http://jsperf.com/css3-calc-test/14 if I understand the results correctly, it says that calc was faster. Did I set it up wrong?

Comment: I just tried your bench test, it says its slow

Comment: @Farhana to me it says that version with calc has about 1500 more operations per second than the margin auto (usually around 40 vs 41.5 thousands).

Comment: @pokrishka I guess browser might make a difference. But I know for a fact that calc is slow.

Comment: @Farhana tested it in other browsers (IE, Firefox) and everywhere version with calc seems to be slightly better (in Firefox significantly, actually, 93 vs 103 thousand operations). Is it because I add 2 nested divs instead of one?

Comment: That could be a reason, did you try one div? but its weird since I just clicked on your link.

Comment: @Farhana here I changed the test to not add any elements to the page but to just switch classes from calc to margin auto: http://jsperf.com/css3-calc-test/18 now calc is about 1% slower on Chrome and about 4% slower on Firefox. But that's not the right test, because I don't just change CSS - if I use calc I have one less nesting on the DOM which should also boost speed a little.

Comment: What exactly do you want to measure?

Comment: @zeroflagL I want to pick best solution in terms of speed + I liked less elements on the layout so calc seems better to me and if the difference is neglectable I would rather use that solution. But I also heard that calc is slow which was not proven by 2 benchmarks I tried to run so I am confused.